# I have a nexus 4 and a window 7 pc. Windows will not install drivers for this device

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a nexus 4 and a window 7 pc. Windows will not install drivers for this device. On the Device Manager it shows up as an error (yellow ?)
Where can i find win 7 drivers for this device and how do I install these drivers?
Windows update does not find any drivers when it does a search of it's Microsoft database.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.guanxin.de/2013/05/installing-nexus-4-adb-drivers-on.html

this may be of some assistance.

Comment: it's generally preferred that you provide a summary here and a link for reference in case the link dies at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource I find for stuff like this is the person that released it:

Straight from [Google](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#WinXp)

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port. Windows will detect the device and launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
2. Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
3. Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
4. Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
5. Click Next to install the driver.

Note, on the linked page is the driver download link.

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced the same problem Download the software from this [link](http://pdanet.co/a/) no need to worry about the software.. If the pc detects the Nexus 4. Uninstall the software and try plug it again to check is that working without the software or not..let me know for you're case. I hope it would help you.